# Preventing multiple form submits in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, updatepanel, postback

I'm currently searching for a way to prevent multiple form submits in ASP.NET (i.e. the user clicks on a submitbutton several times, causing the OnClick-Event to fire several times also).

Currently, I'm doing it like this:

```
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(GetType(), "ServerForm",
        "if (this.submitted) return false; this.submitted = true; return true;");
    }
```

This works like a charm for synchronous postbacks - the 'submitted'-value will be reset after each postback and prevent the form from being submitted multiple times in the same run - however, this method does not work for AsyncPostbacks i.e. with an UpdatePanel, so now I'm searching for an idea to make this happen without having to dis- and enable each and every button via JS after clicking a button.

Thanks,

Dennis

Comment: Because it's an awful lot of JS that I really don't want in my pages, additionally it has to work for several Browsers (hi IE), which really can be a pain to implement, I was hoping to find a simple solution such as this that I can just implement in a class deriving from Page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Page.get_isInAsyncPostBack() in javascript to check the state of async request.

Refer this link for more information:
http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.com/2009/03/prevent-concurrent-asynchronous.html

Answer (score 1):

why not you check in your database ?  if the user already registerd then give a alert box. 
and you can also check [PRG pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)

[Handling Form submission with PRG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8828847/handling-refreshes-after-form-submission/8997855#8997855)

Answer (score 0):

Hopes this will help you.

http://www.techimo.com/forum/webmastering-programming/210441-prevent-multiple-postbacks-javascript-net.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can check the start & end methods present in class`Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager` to check for ASync requests.
2. [Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311028.aspx) You can modify the code in above example & disable the button by using simple javascript like

   `document.getElementById("YouButton.ClientID").disabled = true;`